# VBA to lookup multiple values

Tags: vba, spreadsheet

I have an Spreadsheet with values listed multiple times in multiple columns. Example column `b` thru `d`. Is it possible to lookup each of these values individually and return the values from `Column A`.

**Data Table**

[image: Data Table]

**Output Example**

[image: Example Output]

The output Sheet would already have the values to look up listed in `Column A`.

Comment: vba or vb.net ?

Answer (score 1):

this is vba solution, I did not declare variables, please do it

```
Sub a()
Set sh1 = Sheets(1)
Set sh2 = Sheets(2)
Lastrow2 = sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For r = 2 To Lastrow2
  cable = sh2.Cells(r, 1)
  s = ""
  For Each cell In sh1.UsedRange
    If cell = cable Then s = s + sh1.Cells(cell.Row, 1) + ","
  Next
  sh2.Cells(r, 2) = s
Next
End Sub
```